# Jquery create new datatable with checked rows

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am showing some data in jquery datatable through Ajax call. I have added checkbox in datatable. Now I want to get data of checked rows and create new datable in popup.

I am getting checked rows data from below code and display in alert. How can I create new datatable from below code?

```
$("#table_schedule input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
                var row = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
                message += row.cells[1].innerHTML;
                message += "   " + row.cells[2].innerHTML;
                message += "   " + row.cells[3].innerHTML;
                message += "\n";
 
            //Display selected Row data in Alert Box.
            alert(message);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for example you have this structure for your new table:

```
<div id="content">
    <table class="table table-hover " id="myTable">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>Field 1</th>
                 <th>Field 2</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <td></td> 
                 <td></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

I could do it like this using JQuery:

```
$('#myTable tbody').append('<tr><td>row.cells[1].innerHTML</td><td>row.cells[2].innerHTML</td><td>row.cells[3].innerHTML</td></tr>');
```

If you want to create a new table:

```
 var table = $('<table id="myTable">').addClass('foo');
                
 table.append( '<tr><td>' + row.cells[1].innerHTML +   '</td><td>' + row.cells[2].innerHTML + '</td><td>' + row.cells[3].innerHTML + '</td></tr>' );    
            
 $('#content').append(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table and clone `tr`

```
  $newTable = $("<table>")
  $("#table_schedule input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").clone().appendTo($newTable);
  });

  $newTable.insertAfter("#btn");
```

Please check working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4sqgwofL/)